# Tangent spaces of affine space

Tags: differential-geometry, affine-geometry

An affine space of dimension *n* on $\mathbb R$ is defined to be a non-empty set $E$ such that there exists a vector space $V$ of dimension *n* on $\mathbb R$ and a mapping

$\phi:E \times E \rightarrow V,\space\space\space
     (A,B) \mapsto \phi(A,B):=\vec {AB}$

that obeys the following properties:

(i) For any point $O \in E$, the function

$\phi_O: E \rightarrow V,\space\space\space
      M \mapsto \vec {OM}$

is bijective.

(ii) For any triplet $(A,B,C)$ of elements of $E$, the following relation holds:

$\vec {AB} + \vec {BC} = \vec {AC}.$

People always say that the tangent space at a point $p$ is $V$ but I am having trouble in proof that.
How can we proof that tangent  space is $V$?
My definition of tangent vector $X$ is the linear map $X(f)=\frac{d}{dt}f(\gamma(t))$ where $f$ is real valued function on a manifold and $\gamma$ a curve on a manifold

Comment: Can you prove that given a point $p\in\mathbb R^n$, the tangent space $T_p\mathbb R^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: It depends on what definition of the tangent space you know. But what @Alessandro says is the key point.

Comment: As I pointed out on your earlier post, you need some topological structure here before you can begin to talk about tangent spaces. The bijection needs to be homeomorphism for (some) $O\in E$.

Answer (score 1):

More precisely, for any $A \in E$ there is a natural isomorphism $T_A E \stackrel{\cong}{\to} V$.

**Hint**

1. By axiom (i) a choice of point $O \in E$ defines a bijection $\phi_O := \phi(O, \,\cdot\,): E \to V$, and we can declare this bijection to be a diffeomorphism. Axiom (ii) then implies that the smooth manifold structure defined on $E$ this way does not depend on the choice of $O$.
2. Recall that for any $v \in V$ there is a canonical isomorphism $\Psi_v : T_v V \stackrel{\cong}{\to} V$,

Comment: Thank you for you response, but I am a student of physics so a lot of terminology that you use I do not understand. Words like natural isomorphism, smooth structure  and canonical I am not familiar with them?

Comment: In this setting "canonical" (and "natural") essentially mean that there is not just an isomorphism but actually a way of singling out a special isomorphism. (After all, any two vector spaces over $\Bbb R$ of the same dimension are isomorphic to one another, so once you know that $\dim E = n := \dim V$, it follows immediately that $T_A E \cong \Bbb R^n \cong V$.)

Comment: A "smooth structure" is just the underlying structure on a manifold that lets you perform differentiation in the first place; all the observation in (1) says is that declaring $\phi_O$ to be a diffeomorphism means that you can transfer your notion of differentiation on a vector space to your affine space $E$; put another way (1) says that $E$ and $V$ are (by declaration) the same as smooth manifolds.